# In-app subscription doesn't show test card

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription

- I have implemented in-app subscriptions in my Android app and followed [Instructions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777) :
- I have added one `email` as license tester which is present in my device(`release build`).
  **But it doesn't show test card but shows real card**.
- Also I have uploaded release build my app to `Internal test track` but result is same as above.

> Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 6):

After implementation of In-app subscription next step is adding your google email in Licence Testing [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIvF1.png) is attached.

Automatically Google take 2 to 24 hours to reflect your account as tester. **if you want an immediate response just go and clear storage & cache of your Play Store app**. Happy Testing :-)

Comment: Clear Storage and Cache is not working . It is not showing the Test Card .

Comment: adding your email in Licence Testing if prerequisite. Have you added? @dee

Comment: Thanks for the response mate. Yes I had added the license testers. After struggling for 2-3 hours, I switched to other work and when I tested the build after one day, it was working for me. I think It takes 8-10 hours for license testers to actually using the test account.

Comment: Yes, you are right. it takes some time to reflect the newly added emails as a tester due to the cache of the Google Play store mobile app. But if you want a quick response clear the cache and storage details of the Google Play Application from your device and your email will be reflected as a tester immediately.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally what I did to make it work:

- I have removed all Google Accounts from my device.
- Then, cleared Play Store data.
- I added only single google account in the device that I have registered as license tester, now it is showing test card.

Comment: I did the same but test cards still does not show

Comment: Have you added the email in `google play console` for testing cards?

Comment: I solved it already, I did not add emails in the license tester.

Answer (score 0):

Add your Google Play Store email in License Testing menu.

```
Google Console -> Setup -> License Testing
```